# nullable WSDL message part?

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, wsdl, gsoap

**Problem:**

I have a SOAP service with the following simplified WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://new.webservice.namespace" targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://new.webservice.namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified"/>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="NewMessageRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameter" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="NewMessageResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="result" type="xs:string"/>
        <wsdl:part name="param2" type="xs:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="NewPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:NewMessageRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:NewMessageResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="NewBinding" type="tns:NewPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:#NewOperation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="NewService">
        <wsdl:port name="NewPort" binding="tns:NewBinding">
            <soap:address location="No Target Adress"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

*Notice the output message has two parts.*

When invoking the SOAP services with SoapUI, the services implemented with the gSOAP framework returns a response which does not comply with the WSDL:

This is the SoapUI request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:new="http://new.webservice.namespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <new:NewOperation>
         <parameter>Hello</parameter>
      </new:NewOperation>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the gSOAP WS response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:new="http://new.webservice.namespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <new:NewOperationResponse>
         <result xsi:nil="true"/>
         <param2>Hello World</param2>
      </new:NewOperationResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SoapUI complains with the following error:

```
line5: Element has xsi:nil attribute but is not nillable
```

**Question:**

How can I fix the WSDL so the message part is nullable?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have set the `SOAP_XML_NIL` flag? This flag should not be set. See the gsoap documentation stating for `SOAP_XML_NIL:  output NULLs as xsi:nil`.